# request() use id or name attribute classic ASP

Tags: html, forms, asp-classic

I have a webpage that I need to fix for ADA compliance.  There are a few elements that share `id`s.  The form on the page uses `request()` to grab information, but it doesn't appear to be the `Request` object.  **I'm trying to figure out if this request function? object? uses the `name` or `id` attribute.**  I'm hoping that it's the `name` attribute.

Here's an example of the ASP code:

```vb
if request("submit") = "Submit" then
    session("firstName")            =   request("firstName")
    session("middleInitial")        =   request("middleInitial")
    session("lastName")             =   request("lastName")
end if
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<label>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstName" id="firstName" value="<%=session("firstName")%>"></label>
<label>Middle Initial: <input type="text" name="middleInitial" id="middleInitial" value="<%=session("middleInitial")%>"></label>
<label>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastName" id="lastName" value="<%=session("lastName")%>"></label>
```

Comment: What does this mean? - *"but it doesn't appear to be the `Request` object"*. The statement makes no sense, the `Request` object in Classic ASP is how you retrieve form submitted content in the server-side code period.

Comment: @Lankymart because all of the references I've read use the Request object with an object method.  In the code I'm working with, there is no object method.  It's simply ```request()```, as shown in the example code I provided.  So that leads me to believe that it isn't the Request object.

Comment: The `Request` object contains two collections but uniquely allows you to reference both collections at once. `Request("name")` will return either "name" parameter passed via `GET` or `POST`. `Request.QueryString("name")` returns the parameter `name` from a `GET` request which makes up part of the URLs querystring. `Request.Form("name")` returns the parameter `name` from a `POST` request where the parameters make up the request body. You can also call `Request.QueryString` or `Request.Form` to return a comma delimited string containing all passed parameters by method respectively.

Comment: @Lankymart Thanks, I learned something new.  Everything I had found while googling or reading a reference book didn't explain these concepts very well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `id` is only used client side (primarily for linking, JS, CSS and the `for` attribute).

The `name` is used to describe the data that will be encoded in the form submission (so this is what is available to your server side code).

Comment: That's what I was hoping to hear.  That answers my question, thanks!